# Adding events to my web app, then allow others to extend and add subscribers to those events

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a web application, I want to sprinkle events in places and then let others, who want to extend the functionality, add subscribers to those events.

So something like:

```
Users.PreUserUpdated();

Users.Update(user);

Users.OnUserUpdated();
```

**If someone now wanted to subscribe to the pre or on user updated events, where would they do so? global.asax before application startup?**

Comment: I would perhaps register them in web.config or use MEF. And global.asax is a good place to do it. I assume someone makes dll's which hooks on your event?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend subclassing `System.Web.UI.Page` and expose your events there. Then people can inherit from your class and get access to your events if needed.

Comment: Well I don't want to couple the events with the page as they events will occur in my service classes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BlogEngine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/) and see how they do it. Basically, the model classes have static events that "plugins" can attach to do do processing on them. In the application start event, the plugins in the bin directory are enumerated and a specific method is called on each one which wires up the necessary event handlers.

As an example, here's an event from the Post class that extensions can hook into to manipulate the post content before it is rendered to the page:

```
/// <summary>
/// Occurs when the post is being served to the output stream.
/// </summary>
public static event EventHandler<ServingEventArgs> Serving;

/// <summary>
/// Raises the event in a safe way
/// </summary>
public static void OnServing(Post post, ServingEventArgs arg)
{
    if (Serving != null)
    {
        Serving(post, arg);
    }
}
```

And one of the extensions that hooks into it:

```
[Extension("Converts ASCII smilies into real smilies in the comments", "1.3", "BlogEngine.NET")]
public class Smilies
{

    static Smilies()
    {
        Comment.Serving += new EventHandler<ServingEventArgs>(Post_CommentServing);
    }

    private const string LINK = "<img src=\"{0}editors/tiny_mce3/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-{1}.gif\" class=\"flag\" alt=\"{2}\" />";

    /// <summary>
    /// The event handler that is triggered every time a comment is served to a client.
    /// </summary>
    private static void Post_CommentServing(object sender, ServingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Body))
        {
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("(H)", Convert("cool", "Cool"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":'(", Convert("cry", "Cry"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":$", Convert("embarassed", "Embarassed"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":|", Convert("foot-in-mouth", "Foot"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":(", Convert("frown", "Frown"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("(A)", Convert("innocent", "Innocent"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("(K)", Convert("kiss", "Kiss"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":D", Convert("laughing", "Laughing"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("($)", Convert("money-mouth", "Money"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":-#", Convert("sealed", "Sealed"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":)", Convert("smile", "Smile"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":-)", Convert("smile", "Smile"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":-O", Convert("surprised", "Surprised"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(":P", Convert("tongue-out", "Tong"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("*-)", Convert("undecided", "Undecided"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace(";-)", Convert("wink", "Wink"));
            e.Body = e.Body.Replace("8o|", Convert("yell", "Yell"));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Formats the anchor and inserts the right smiley image.
    /// </summary>
    private static string Convert(string name, string alt)
    {
        return string.Format(LINK, Utils.RelativeWebRoot, name, alt);
    }
}
```